# seeing notifications of GitHub issues from a fork in original repro

Tags: github, issue-tracking

Someone has created a fork of one of my GitHub private repro's (they have permission, as I made them a collaborator).

They are creating/submitting issues on their fork.

They are assigning those issues to me (as the original repro owner).

I get emails about the issues, but I want to see the issues in my own/original repro.

Is this possible?

Or...

For me to have all of the issues in one place, they must submit those issues to my https://github.com/my-username/my-repro ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not natively with GitHub.

One solution would be to create on the fork a [webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) which, on a issue event, would publish a [JSON payload](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/#payloads) describing said event.

If you have a server listening to that payload, it could through [GitHub API on issues](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/), duplicate the issue of the private repo into your own original private repo.

---

The other workaround is to agree to summit any issue into *one* repo, but that means the discussions around those issues will reference by default the code of that repo.